# Cloudinary-React Could not find a declaration file for module 'cloudinary-react' - Not using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cloudinary

I am trying to `import { Image } from "cloudinary-react";` As instructed at [Cloudinary-React](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary-react)

And getting the warning:

> Could not find a declaration file for module 'cloudinary-react'.
> '/Users/myname/Web
> Projects/ProjectName/node_modules/cloudinary-react/dist/cloudinary-react.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/cloudinary-react` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts)
> file containing `declare module 'cloudinary-react';`ts(7016)

**I am not using TypeScript**.

I can not figure out what is going on. Does anyone have any ideas how I can resolve this? I have looked around for a few hours.

Package.json: `"dependencies": { "axios": "^0.21.1", "bcrypt": "^5.0.0", "cloudinary": "^1.27.1", "cloudinary-react": "^1.7.0", ...`

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

The [cloudinary-react module](https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/cloudinary-react) should normally be added in the `node_modules` when it is installed in your project. The following sample code is shown in this [sample project](https://codesandbox.io/s/cldfrontenddemo001-n70l3).

For the dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "cloudinary-react": "1.7.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0"
},
```

And Cloudinary components can be imported as shown below:

```
import React from "react";

import { Image } from "cloudinary-react";

class ImageDisplay extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="counter">
        <Image cloudName="demo" publicId="sample" width="300" crop="scale" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageDisplay;
```